# find all entries having type_id:ObjectId('random id')

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to repair a mongodb database where in some of the type_id ObjectId got inserted
i tried to use regex but this is not working

```
find({"type_id":{$regex:/ObjectId\(.*\)/}})
```

Any Suggestion?

Comment: Clarity:  Are you asking to find docs where field `type_id` is of type `ObjectId`?   You say some got inserted as `ObjectId`; what are the others, and what do you ultimately view as "fixed"?

Comment: Yes i am asking to find doc where type_id is of type ObjectId

Answer (score 2):

Simple version:

```
db.foo.find({"type_id": {$type: "objectId"}});
```

Using the agg pipeline.  I prefer pipelines because as your expression complexity grows, you don't get bound into the older, smaller feature set of `find`:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
    { $match: {$expr: {$eq: [{$type:"$type_id"}, "objectId"]} }}
]);
```

Look at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type to find the string values returned by `$type`.